# Convert project without introducing bugs

Tags: c++, unit-testing, automation

I have the C++ code of a exe which contains a UI and some process.
My goal is to separate the UI from the process and to convert the exe into a dll.

In order to do that, I am thinking of generating unit test before touching any code and then to do my modification and make sure the tests are not failing.

The problem is that I am not sure if this is the best approach and if it is, is there a way to automatically generate unit test.

BTW, I am using VS 2012.
Do you have any guidance for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no tools for automatically bringing existing code under unit tests - if it were that easy, there should be no new bugs at all, right? As arne says in his answer, if code was not designed to be tested in the first place, it usually has to be changed to be testable.

The best you can do in my opinion is to learn some techniques of how to introduce unit tests with relatively few changes (so that you can introduce the unit tests before you start the "real" modifications); one book on this subject I've read recently is Michael Feathers' "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" (Amazon Link: [http://www.amazon.com/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Michael-Feathers/dp/0131177052](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052)). Although it has some shortcomings, it has pretty detailed descriptions of techniques how you can easily introduce unit tests.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Working Effectively with Legacy Code, although this question as a whole is better suited for Programmers.SE

Answer (score 5):

It's relatively hard to write meaningful unit tests for GUIs. There are frameworks like [FrogLogic's Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/) that make GUI testing relatively easy, but most often, these tools are not free.

Note also that it is no small feat to write unit tests "after the fact", as the original code might already have to be changed to make it testable.